# best way to write a puppet manifest for adding Linux auto.misc entries without overwriting the existing config lines

Tags: puppet, augeas, automount

I am currently writing a puppet module for adding lines to auto.misc file.

I used augeas for adding a new entry to the auto.misc file and I came up with like something below and it works quite well every time I run without duplicating.

```
augeas { "new auto mountpoint":

        context => "/files/etc/auto.misc",
        changes => [

            "set 01 'store'",
            "set 01/opt[1] 'ro'",
            "set 01/opt[2] 'soft'",
            "set 01/opt[3] 'intr'",
            "set 01/location/1/host 'uxkickstart.thenational.com'",
            "set 01/location/1/path '/common'",
        ],

        onlyif  => "match *[. = 'store'] size == 0",
    }
```

Now if i want to add a new option for a particular mount-point , it never gets updated.

If someone could tell me whats the best way to do this or use augeas in a different way to fix the issue here, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to add/modify a line at a time, then the [file_line](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#file_line) resource from [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) is way easier to use than augeas.

Comment: I did try that but the drawback is, it will add an duplicate entry even when a single word from that line it is looking to replace is missing.

Comment: You should be able to do this with the match parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The best option here is to write a proper type+augeas provider instead of using the `augeas` type. This will let you specify the options as an array property.

See [augeasproviders.com](http://augeasproviders.com) for examples, and various modules implementing augeas providers [on github](https://github.com/hercules-team/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=augeasproviders).